# Windows 10: Can't login after current user account is deleted

Tags: windows-10, login

I've disabled login user name change.
After deleted the user account (local user account with admin permission), I'm not able to log in windows.

Shift-restart, start troubleshoot, command prompt.
Create the same user account with same password and add to admin group.
But after restart, still not able to log in. If open troubleshoot command prompt again, run command 'net user', can't see new created user account.
Seems all changes made in troubleshoot command prompt are lost.

If select to boot safe mode, because I've set administrator need to set new password on next login, can't directly log in administrator account.
Set new password, it will print "Access is denied".

Not sure if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The account you deleted was the normal Administrator account (assuming local machine and not domain). Also I am not referring to the built-in Administrator account.

Is the local Account a Microsoft Account?  It does not appear to be from the above, but please let us know.

Then finally if you have altered the built-in Admin Account, and cannot log in using Safe Mode, then I do not see how you can fix this.

Comment: It's a local account, not Microsoft account. Not able to log in with built-in Administrator account in safe mode.

Comment: You need to install Windows again to correct this. I do not alter the built-in Admin account as it can be used in Safe Mode to get going again.